# current, correct way to update nodejs and node-red on raspberry pi?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, node-red

Attempting to update my three raspberry-pi NodeRed installations, I am getting these errors:

```
node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node)
```

Any methods I have used have failed to install/update Node.js.

At this point I am fine with completely removing node-red and nodejs and re-installing from scratch.

So:

How can I correctly update Node.js and node-red at this point? 
or
How can I completely remove node.js and node-red and start over?

EDIT:

PI - 2 Model B (BCM2835, rev a21041). Running Jessie 4.9.35v7+ 2017-07-05.

Running script from https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/raspberrypi results in this error:

```
/dev/fd/63: line 298: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/dev/fd/63: line 298: `        fi'
```

This happened early on, and I went down a lot of side roads from various google searches, trying different approaches. Did not leave myself enough breadcrumbs to re-create exactly how I got here, unfortunately. I used scripts from different github sites using NPM or bash<-curl(my-version-of-update-nodejs-and-nodered).

Comment: Run the script again, it's been changed twice today specifically around that line to add some new checks. Looks like you were in the gap between the 2 edits.

Comment: Also Jessie is very old, you should back up your data and wipe the SD card and start again.

Comment: The script now runs without the syntax error, but returns the same complaints about the 2 libraries. Based on your comments, I'm wiping the SD card and downloading newer Pi-OS image. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to both install and upgrade Node-RED on a Raspberry Pi is to use the install script linked to from the Node-RED install docs [here](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/raspberrypi).

This script will remove any current version of NodeJS and Node-RED and install the latest version that will work on the correct processor in the Pi (e.g. NodeJS don't formally ship a build that will run on a Raspberry Pi Zero anymore)

Comment: the bash < curl command returned the following:
/dev/fd/63: line 298: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/dev/fd/63: line 298: `        fi'